# I can't get the value of my datetimepicker in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

everyone, I made some changes and find out that there is no problem with the datetimepickers. The data is returning correctly, but I do not show it, I show the one, which is loaded at the start. I will give you some images and I would be so thankful if you tell me how to find out where my function should be called.

When you first go into the page, where I want to show information from the database, everything is working (I have set default values if the datetimepickers are empty).

Then I put some values in the datetimepickers and the following executions are made:
[image: this is my function whit the correct results 1]

[image: this is my function whit the correct results 2]

[image: this is the execution of which the data in my table is showed 1]

[image: this is the execution of which the data in my table is showed 2]

I really do not know from where this currentController came from and how to connect it with my function TaskReportPerPeriod. I mean, everything is working, because the data is returning correctly, but somehow in the table is showed the result from currentController...., but there I want to show the results from TaskReportPerPeriod only.

TaskReportPerPeriod:

```
public function actionTaskReportPerPeriod()
    {
        $aColumns = array(
          'task_id',
          'trans_type',
          'task_description',
          'driver_name',
          'customer_name',
          'delivery_address',
          'delivery_date' ,
          'status'
        
        );

        $date_from = isset($this->data['task_report_start_date'])?$this->data['task_report_start_date']:date('2021-09-20 00:00:00');
        $date_to = isset($this->data['task_report_end_date'])?$this->data['task_report_end_date']:date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        

        $t=AjaxDataTables::AjaxData($aColumns);     
        if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
            dump($t);
        }
        
        if (is_array($t) && count($t)>=1){
            $sWhere=$t['sWhere'];
            $sOrder=$t['sOrder'];
            $sLimit=$t['sLimit'];
        }   
                
        $and='';        
        $and=" AND delivery_date >= '$date_from' AND delivery_date <= '$date_to' AND customer_id =".Driver::q(Driver::getUserId())."  ";
        
        $stmt="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
        FROM
        {{driver_task_view}}
        WHERE 1     
        $and
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
        if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
           dump($stmt);
        }
        
//      dump($this->data);
//      dump($stmt);
        
        $_SESSION['kartero_stmt_taskList']=$stmt;
                
        $DbExt=new DbExt; 
        $DbExt->qry("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1");
        
        if ( $res=$DbExt->rst($stmt)){
            
            $iTotalRecords=0;                       
            $stmtc="SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_records";
            if ( $resc=$DbExt->rst($stmtc)){                                    
                $iTotalRecords=$resc[0]['total_records'];
            }
            
            $feed_data['sEcho']=intval($_GET['sEcho']);
            $feed_data['iTotalRecords']=$iTotalRecords;
            $feed_data['iTotalDisplayRecords']=$iTotalRecords;                                      
            
            foreach ($res as $val) {
                $date_created=AdminFunctions::prettyDate($val['delivery_date'],true);
                $date_created=Yii::app()->functions->translateDate($date_created);      
                
                $status="<span class=\"tag ".$val['status']." \">".Driver::t($val['status'])."</span>"; 
                
                $action="<a class=\"btn btn-primary task-details\"
                    data-id=\"".$val['task_id']."\" href=\"javascript:;\">".t("Details")."</a>";
                
                if ( $val['status']=="unassigned"){
                    $action="<a class=\"btn btn-default assign-agent\"
                    data-id=\"".$val['task_id']."\" href=\"javascript:;\">".Driver::t("Assigned")."</a>";
                }
                
                $ratings='<div class="raty-stars" data-score="'.$val['ratings'].'"></div>';

                    $feed_data['aaData'][]=array(
                  $val['task_id'],
                  date("Y-m-d",strtotime($val['delivery_date'])),
                  Driver::t($val['trans_type']),
                  $val['task_description'],
                  $val['driver_name'],
                  $val['customer_name'],
                  $val['delivery_address'],
                  $date_created,
                  $ratings,
                  $val['rating_comment'],

                  $val['dropoff_contact_name'], 
                  $val['drop_address'],
                  $val['dropoff_task_lat']."  ". $val['dropoff_task_lng'],
                  $val['Task_insert_root'],

                  
                 
                 
                 
                         
                  $val['delivery_charge'],//Driver::t("Delivery fee"), 
                  $val['team_name'],//   Driver::t("City"), 
                  $val['distance_assigned_to_pickup'],//Driver::t("Pickup distance"), 
                  $val['distance_pickup_to_dropoff'],//Driver::t("Dropoff distance"), 
                  $val['arrived_at_pickup'],//Driver::t("Arrived at restaurant"), 
                  $val['delivery_date'],//Driver::t("Delivery_date"), 
            
                  $val['dropoff_before'],//Driver::t("dropoff_before"), 
                  $val['arrived_at_dropoff'],//Driver::t("Arrived at dropoff"), 
                  $val['stoppage_at_pickup'],//Driver::t("Driver at restaurant time"), 
                  $val['delay_pickup'],//Driver::t("Vendor late pickup"), 
                  $val['delay_dropoff'],//Driver::t("Driver late dropoff"),
                  $val['total_w_tax'],//Driver::t("Driver late dropoff"),
                  $val['dropoff_contact_number'],//Driver::t("Driver late dropoff")
                  $val['payment_type'],//Driver::t("Driver late dropoff")

                  

                  $status ,
                  $action


                
                );              
            }
            if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
               dump($feed_data);
            }
        // dump($feed_data);
            $this->otableOutput($feed_data);    
        }
        
        $this->otableNodata();
    }
```

Here I am calling the above function:

```
    $( document ).on( "click", ".generate-task", function() {   
        debugger;
        var params= "task_report_start_date" + $(task_report_start_date).val();
        params+= "&task_report_end_date" + $(task_report_end_date).val();

            console.log('test console output'); 
            callAjax("TaskReportPerPeriod",params);
            tableReload();
        
        });
```

Here is callAjax:

```
function callAjax(action,params,button)
{
    debugger;
    params+="&language="+language;
    
    ajax_request = $.ajax({
    url: ajax_url+"/"+action,
    method: "post" ,
    data: params ,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: ajax_timeout,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {       
        if ((typeof  ajax_request !== "undefined") && ( ajax_request !== null)) {
            ajax_request.abort();
            busy(false,button);
        } else {
            busy(true,button);  
        }               
    }
    });
            
    ajax_request.done(function( data ) {
    //  debugger;
        busy(false,button);
        dump(data);

    });
    /*END DONE*/

    ajax_request.always(function() {       
    ajax_request = null;   
    });
        
    /*FAIL*/
    ajax_request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {       

        $text = !empty(jqXHR.responseText)?jqXHR.responseText:'';
        if(textStatus!="abort"){
        nAlert( textStatus + "\n" + $text , "warning"); 
        }
            
    });         
}
```

Here is my frontend:

```
<div id="layout_1">
<?php 
$this->renderPartial('/tpl/layout1_top',array(   
));
?> 
</div> <!--layout_1-->

<div class="parent-wrapper task-list-area">

 <div class="content_1 white">   
   <?php 
   $this->renderPartial('/tpl/menu',array(   
   ));
   ?>
 </div> <!--content_1-->
 
 <div class="content_main">

   <div class="nav_option">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 border">
         <b><?php echo t("Task report per period")?></b>
        </div> <!--col-->
        <div class="col-md-6 border text-right">
                       
           <a class="orange-button left rounded" href="javascript:tableReload();"><?php echo t("Refresh")?></a>
           
           <a class="green-button left rounded" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/app/export_task')?>">
           <?php echo t("Export")?>
           </a>           
         
        </div> <!--col-->
      </div> <!--row-->
   </div> <!--nav_option-->


   <div class="row top6">
            <div class="col-md-1 ">
                 <h5 class="top2"><?php echo Driver::t("From date ")?></h5> 
            </div>
            <span class="col-md-1 "><?php echo CHtml::textField('task_report_start_date','',array(//delivery before calendar
                'placeholder'=>Driver::t("From date"),
                'required'=>true,
                'class'=>"datetimepicker"
              ))?>
            </span>

            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
                 <h5 class="top2"><?php echo Driver::t("To date ")?></h5> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 "><?php echo CHtml::textField('task_report_end_date','',array(//delivery before calendar
                'placeholder'=>Driver::t("To date"),
                'required'=>true,
                'class'=>"datetimepicker"
              ))?>
            </div>

            <button type="button" data-id=".generate-task" 
            class="generate-task green-button inline rounded"><?php echo t("Generate Report")?></button>
    </div> <!--row-->
  
   <div class="inner">
   <form id="frm_table" class="frm_table">
   <?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('action','TaskReportPerPeriod')?>
   <table id="table_list" class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%"><?php echo t("Task ID")?></th>     
      <th><?php echo t("Data")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo t("Task Type")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Description")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Driver Name")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Name")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Address")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Delivery Date")?></th>
      <th width="3%"><?php echo t("Ratings")?></th>
      <th width="2%"><?php echo t("Ratings Comments")?></th>

      <th><?php echo t("Customer Name")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo t("Customer Address")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Cust map coord")?></th>
      <th><?php echo t("Task source")?></th>
      
 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Delivery fee")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("City")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Pickup distance")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Dropoff distance")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Arrived at restaurant")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Pickup")?></th> 

      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Dropoff")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Arrived at dropoff")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Driver at restaurant time")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Vendor late pickup")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Driver late dropoff")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Total")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Customer's phone")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Payment type")?></th> 
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Status")?></th>      
      <th><?php echo Driver::t("Check")?></th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
    </tbody>     
   </table>
   </form>
   </div>
 
 </div> <!--content_2-->

</div> <!--parent-wrapper-->
```

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem?  Where are you stuck? What do you mean by that "parseerror"?

Comment: How, when and where is `$this->data` created? If the dump of this property is the one you posted (at what point in the code is the dump made?), the problem is not in the code you posted, but some step before. Probably, this array should have the date string in the value and not in the key.

Comment: Hi, guys, I have edited my question. I hope that now is a bit more clearly.

Comment: As you have removed all code from your question, it's impossible to tell you where this goes wrong

Comment: Please do not just dump code, but explain what the problem is and what you've tried to resolve it